# Caching architecture for currency exchange rates

Tags: caching

I have a web application that shows currency exchange rates . The rates are stored in an IBM Mainframe  and rates are available through web services. Each time a user accesses the rates page, the page makes a request to the mainframe. This generates too much load on the mainframe. Especially most of the time the rates delivered is the same. How would I design a caching architecture that minimises the trip to the web service. But at the same time rates may fluctuate within the day and if rates have changed the rates web page should not display the cached values but make another request to the web service. How would I design such a caching architecture and make sure it is invalidated on rate changes?

Comment: -1 It's question usually asked by an IT Company based in UAE

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that just a straight forward use of [MemcacheD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached)?